# Delete element of linked list by a certain criterion

Tags: c

I've written this function:

```
List* delPaintingCode(List* head, char *code)
{
    List *p,*q;

    for(p=head;p!=NULL;q=p,p=p->next)
    {
        if(!strcmp(code,p->code))
        {
            if (p==head)
            {
                q=head;
                head=p->next;
                free(q);
            }
            else
            {
                q->next=p->next;
                free(p);
                p=q;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

and when I call it in another function:

```
void delpainting()
{ 
    char code[50];
    printf("code ");
    scanf("%s",code);

    List *head=NULL;

    head=delPaintingCode(filetolist,code);
}
```

the program crashes so. I have a warning: `passing argument 1 of delPaintingCode from incompatible pointer type`

So how should I pass the string to the function?

Comment: What is `filetolist`?

Comment: "how should I pass the string to the function" - it looks like you should instead be asking "What should I pass as the `List` pointer to the function. That warning isn't there by random chance.

Answer (score 1):

The logical problem that leads to a crash is in the `if (p==head)` branch of your code: when you delete the initial element, you free the `head` without updating `p`. This leads to dereferencing a freed pointer on the very next iteration.

You can fix the problem by introducing a fake node with `head` in its `next`, and returning the `next`, like this:

```
List fake;
fake.next = head;
// This loop always looks ahead by one element, i.e. at p->next.
for(List *p = &fake ; p->next != NULL ; p = p->next) {
    if(strcmp(code, p->next->code)) {
        continue;
    }
    List *q = p->next;
    p->next = q->next;
    free(q);
}
return fake.next;
```

This approach works for the initial element, too, because we added a fake head to our list, so the first time around `p->next` is the same as head. This lets us unify treatment of head element and all other elements.