# Deleting multiple nodes from simple linked list on C

Tags: c, list, linked-list, nodes, erase

I want to delete all nodes that have the same idteam as key, but it will crash... I know it should also free() the memory, but anyway I thought this should work :S

```
//defining the struct
struct players {
   int idplayer;
   int idteam;
   struct players *next;
 };

 struct players *first, *last;

//the function to delete the nodes
void delete(int key){
 struct players *post;
 struct players *pre;
 struct players *auxi;

 auxi = first; //initialization of auxi
 while(auxi != NULL) //this should run the loop till the end of the list?
 {
    if(auxi->idteam == key){ //condition to delete
        if(auxi == first) first = auxi->next; //erase for the case the node is the first one
        else pre->next = post; //erase in the case the node is anywhere else
      }
      pre = auxi; //saves the current value of auxi
      auxi = auxi->next; //increments the position of auxi
      post = auxi->next; //saves the position of the next element
     }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578168/971127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  auxi = auxi->next; //increments the position of auxi
  post = auxi->next; //saves the position of the next element
```

When `auxi` becomes `NULL`, you will end up doing `post = (NULL)->next;`, which is an access violation (crash).

You don't really need `post`, just do:

```
if(auxi->idteam == key){ 
    if(auxi == first) first = auxi->next; 
    else pre->next = auxi->next; // We know auxi is not NULL, so this is safe.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong.

In this code snippet

```
  pre = auxi; //saves the current value of auxi
  auxi = auxi->next; //increments the position of auxi
  post = auxi->next; //saves the position of the next element
```

after statement

```
  auxi = auxi->next; //increments the position of auxi
```

auxi can be equal to NULL so the next statement

```
  post = auxi->next; //saves the position of the next element
```

results in undefined behaviour.

But it is not the only mistake. Also you have to set correctly node `last`.

And you have to free deleted nodes.

The function can look the following way

```
void delete( int key )
{
    struct players *prev = NULL;
    struct players *auxi = first;;

    while ( auxi != NULL )
    {
        if ( auxi->idteam == key )
        {
            struct players *tmp = auxi;

            if ( auxi == first ) first = auxi->next;
            else prev->next = auxi->next;

            if ( auxi == last ) last = prev; 

            auxi = auxi->next; 

            free( tmp );
      }
}
```