# Delete string from linked list - C

Tags: c, string, linked-list

So the problem I'm running into is deleting a user-inputted string from a linked list full of strings.

I'm still having a few issues in understanding *just* precisely how linked lists work, so any explanation as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!
Also, every other function seems to be working just fine, just having issues with the `deleteItem` function!

Edit - The problem I'm getting when I run the `deleteItem` function is just my terminal window crashing after getting hung up for a bit.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
}*head;

void display();
void insert();
void count();
void deleteItem();
int main(){

int choice = 1;
char name[50];

struct node *first;
head = NULL;

while(1){
        printf("Menu Options\n");
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("Please enter the number of the operation you'd like to do: \n");
        printf("----------------\n");
        printf("1. Insert\n");
        printf("2. Display\n");
        printf("3. Count\n");
        printf("4. Delete\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("----------------\n");

        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                insert();
                break;
            case 2:
                display();
                 break;
            case 3:
                count();
                break;
            case 4:
                if(head=NULL)
                    printf("The list is blank");
                else
                    deleteItem();
                break;
            case 5:
               return 0;
            default:
                printf("invalid option");
            }
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}

void insert(){

 char nameToInsert[50];
 struct node *temp;

temp = head;
 if(head == NULL){
         head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

         printf("What's the name you wish to insert?\n");
         scanf("%s", &nameToInsert);

         strcpy(head->name, nameToInsert);
         head->next = NULL;
         }

 else{
      while(temp->next !=NULL){
                       temp = temp->next;
                       }
         temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         temp = temp->next;

         printf("What's the name you wish to insert?\n");
         scanf("%s", &nameToInsert);

         strcpy(temp->name, nameToInsert);

         temp->next = NULL;
         }

}

void display(){

 struct node *temp;
 temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 temp = head;

 if(temp == NULL)
         printf("The list is empty\n");

 else{
      printf("%s\n", temp->name);

      while(temp->next != NULL){
       temp = temp->next;
       printf("%s\n", temp->name);
       }

 }

}

void count(){
    struct node *temp;
    int c =0;
    temp = head;

    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
        c++;
    }
    printf("\n%d", c);
}

void deleteItem(){
    char nameToDelete[50];
    struct node *temp, *previous;
    temp = head;

    printf("What is the name you wish to delete?\n");
    scanf("%s", nameToDelete);

    while(temp->next != NULL){
           temp = temp->next;
           if(strcmp(nameToDelete, temp->name)==0){
            previous = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            printf("%s was deleted successfully\n", nameToDelete);
           }

        }

}
```

Comment: 0) `if(head=NULL)` should be `if(head==NULL)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you! That fixed one of the problems! Still getting the crash when trying to delete the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578168/971127

Comment: Crap, I didn't try searching using that term... Thanks, @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following issues:

1. You are not dealing with the case where the item to delete is at the head of the list.
2. The linked list is not restored to a good state after you `free` the node that contains the item.
3. You continue to iterate over the list even after you `free` the node that contains the item.

Here's a version that should work.

```
void deleteItem(){
   char nameToDelete[50];
   struct node *temp, *previous;
   temp = head;

   printf("What is the name you wish to delete?\n");
   scanf("%s", nameToDelete);

   // First, locate the node that contains the item.
   for ( ; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next )
   {
      if(strcmp(nameToDelete, temp->name)==0)
      {
         break;
      }
      prev = temp;
   }

   // Now take care of deleting it.
   if ( temp != NULL )
   {
      if ( temp == head )
      {
         head = temp->next;
      }
      else
      {
         prev->next = temp->next;
      }

      free(temp);
      printf("%s was deleted successfully\n", nameToDelete);
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation! Question though: why is there a "floating" `;` in the beginning of the first for loop?
@R Sahu

Comment: Herp, disregard previous comment, I just realized it. Thank you again!

Comment: @bravesaint, that is a syntactic requirement of the `for` loop.

Comment: @R Sahu I just realized it... This is what happens first assignment back after being out of class (and sadly away from programming) for a month or so...