# ,C, Crash while try to delete last element in a list

Tags: c, list, crash, free

my program's aim is to delete all the elements with a numeric even value. The program works fine, except when it should delete the last element: that makes the program crash.

I have created a list with this structure:

```
struct elemento{
       int dato;
       struct elemento *next;
};
```

You can ignore how the list is created, since i know that the error is only in this function:

```
struct elemento *eliminapari(struct elemento *p){

   struct elemento * start = p;
   struct elemento * temp, *temp2;
   int cont;
   cont = 0;
   temp2 = p;
   while(p != NULL && cont != 20){
         temp2 = temp2->next;

         if((p->dato % 2) == 0){
             if (cont == 0){ //if first element 
                start = p->next;
                free(p);
                p = start;

             }else if(p->next == NULL){ //if last element
                temp2->next = NULL; //this would be the previous node
                free(p);
                p = NULL;

             }else{
                temp = p->next;
                p->dato = p->next->dato;
                p->next = p->next->next;
                free(temp);

             }
         }else{printf("\n3\n"); p = p->next;}

       cont = cont + 1;  
   }

       return(start);

   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where does it crash, how does it crash, what's in the structures at the time, how are the structures declared, how does the data get allocated, how do you know it hasn't been freed already?  We're not mind-readers.

Comment: `temp2->next = NULL; //this would be the previous node` : `temp2` to be `NULL`

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing but my guess would be that you're freeing a NULL pointer, try to free the pointer before you set it to NULL

Comment: Guys, the problem is the else if clause, where there's the commet "//if last element". As BLUEPIXY said, that row was the problem, but i still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: such like as http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578168/971127

Answer (score 2):

Go through what will happen if you call eliminapari passing p as a the only struct instance (in other words, p->next is NULL. then the first line inside the while loop sets temp2 == NULL. But then in the "else" clauses you try to dereference temp2 (temp2->next = NULL), but temp2 is NULL, so *Crash*.

Comment: ok, that makes the program crash, but how to solve the problem? if i just delete that row, the only free, does not deference the pointer to last element. How to solve?